# Error en crear un Usuario en Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

Estoy aprendiendo en oracle 11g pero tengo el problema a la hora de crear un USUARIO

```
create user ALUMNO

identified by 123456
default tablespace users 
temporary tablespace temp
profile default ;
```

hasta aca me sale que el usurio fue creado pero al poner sus privilegios
me sale error

```
grant connect resource to ALUMNO;
grant connect any table to ALUMNO;
grant connect any synonym to ALUMNO;
```

---

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 11 del comando :
grant connect resource to ALUMNO
Informe de error -
ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
00990. 00000 -  "missing or invalid privilege"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error que empieza en la línea: 12 del comando :
grant connect any table to ALUMNO
Informe de error -
ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
00990. 00000 -  "missing or invalid privilege"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error que empieza en la línea: 13 del comando :
grant connect any synonym to ALUMNO
Informe de error -
ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
00990. 00000 -  "missing or invalid privilege"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

y si lo cambio por grant create me sale GRANT CORRECT  en any table , any synonym pero en resource
me sale error

```
grant create resource to ALUMNO;
grant create any table to ALUMNO;
grant create any synonym to ALUMNO;
```

---

```
 Error que empieza en la línea: 9 del comando :
grant create resource to ALUMNO
Informe de error -
ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
00990. 00000 -  "missing or invalid privilege"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Y si le pongo el `alter session "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;` me sale el siguiente error

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 4 del comando :
alter session "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true
Informe de error -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Si alguien sabe me podria decir cual seria la solucion a mi problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando de dar permisos a privilegios o roles que no existen. Para dejarlo más claro, veamos el primer error:

No hay ningún privilegio llamado `connect resource` que puedas otorgar a tu usuario. Es básicamente lo que te dice el mensaje de error (y es cierto):

> ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege

Puede traducirse como:

> ORA-00990: Privilegio inválido o faltante

Dado que por defecto hay un rol llamado `connect`, al que podrías darle permiso. También hay otro rol llamado `resource`, quizás lo que te está faltando es una coma, porque quieras darle permiso a ambos roles. En ese caso, la sentencia debiera ser:

```
grant connect, resource to Alumno;
/
```

Que es lo equivalente a estas dos sentencias separadas:

```
grant connect to Alumno;
grant resource to Alumno;
/
```

Como ves, los permisos a roles o privilegios pueden otorgarse en una sola sentencia, en una lista separada por comas.

Entre paréntesis, quiero mencionar que debes tener en cuenta, sin embargo, que estos roles están marcados como obsoletos y desaparecerán en el futuro.  Puedes leer más al respecto en [Addressing The CONNECT Role Change](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/appendixa.htm#CHDGJGJF) de la guía de seguridad (en inglés).

Volviendo al tema, esto mismo está ocurriendo con las otras sentencias. En resumen:

**No puedes dar permisos a un privilegio que no existe**

Te sugiero leer la documentación sobre los [roles y privilegios](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm#DBSEG10000), para encontrar los que quieres asignarle al usuario, que es probable que te estén faltando o sobrando caracteres en alguno de los que te interesa.